# best approximation property of finite dimensional banach space.

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis

recently i am stuck in a question whose partly answer is known to me. But i want full answer. Can anyone help me?

The question is following:

Suppose $X$ is a finite dimensional normed linear space and $S$ be its unit sphere (i.e.set of vectors of length 1). Assume $S$ contains a line segment(i.e. there exist two vector $a,b\in S$ such that $ta+(1-t)b \in S$ for $t\in [0,1]$. Does it necessarily imply $X$ contains a one dimensional affine subspace $L$ containing the line segment $[a,b]$ such that every point of $L$ has norm greater than or equal to $1$.

Actually if this is true then we will have the following result, namely if every one dimensional subspace $Y$ of $X$ has the unique best approximation property (i.e. for each $z\in X , d(z,Y)$ attained at exactly one vector of $Y$)then unit ball of $X$ is strictly convex.

I know the result is true for real normed linear space.But not able to prove it for Complex linear space.In the real case one take the affine subspace as {$ta+(1-t)b:t\in\mathbb{R}$}. But which affine subspace will work for complex linear space case?

Comment: @Federica:Thanks Federica for correcting my mistake.